# make Wordpress image captions responsive

Tags: responsive, captions

[This webpage](http://steven.doig.com.au/) contains images inserted by Wordpress.  The code used to insert the first image is:

```
[caption id="attachment_887" align="alignnone" width="604"]
    <a href="http://steven.doig.com.au/files/2013/06/Forest_Legacy_m.jpg">
        <img class="size-large wp-image-887" alt="a Forest Legacy group" src="http://steven.doig.com.au/files/2013/06/Forest_Legacy_m-1024x681.jpg" width="1024" height="681" />
    </a> a Forest Legacy group[/caption]
```

This image is controlled by CSS:

```
#content .wp-caption a img {
    width: 614px;
    height: auto;
}
```

I want to make this image responsive.  I've inserted the CSS:

```
@media (max-width:988px) {
    #content .wp-caption a img {
        width: 99.03225806%; /* 614/620 */
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

However, the DIV.wp-caption remains at 604px, as specified inside the Wordpress post.  I've tried specifying this as a percentage (97.41935483%) but Wordpress reinterpreted it as 104px.

**The inline CSS is overriding the CSS I insert into the stylesheet.**

```
<div id="attachment_887" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 614px">
```

Any ideas on how I can make the .wp-caption responsive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're going to want to use:

```
@media (max-width: 988px){
  .wp-caption {
    /* Force the box to be 100% */
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  #content .wp-caption a img {
    /* Scale down if too big */
    max-width: 99.03225806%; /* 614/620 */
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility is to change the shortcode output so that the width is no longer hard-coded.  Modifying the Codex example to have no width:

```
add_filter('img_caption_shortcode', 'my_img_caption_shortcode_filter',10,3);

/**
 * Filter to replace the [caption] shortcode text with HTML5 compliant code
 *
 * @return text HTML content describing embedded figure
 **/
function my_img_caption_shortcode_filter($val, $attr, $content = null)
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id'    => '',
        'align' => '',
        'width' => '',
        'caption' => ''
    ), $attr));

    if ( 1 > (int) $width || empty($caption) )
        return $val;

    $capid = '';
    if ( $id ) {
        $id = esc_attr($id);
        $capid = 'id="figcaption_'. $id . '" ';
        $id = 'id="' . $id . '" aria-labelledby="figcaption_' . $id . '" ';
    }

    return '<figure ' . $id . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr($align) . '" >'
    . do_shortcode( $content ) . '<figcaption ' . $capid 
    . 'class="wp-caption-text">' . $caption . '</figcaption></figure>';
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter#Example

Answer (score 5):

Here's a much simpler and cleaner solution:

```
function my_img_caption_shortcode_width($width, $atts, $content)
{
    return 0;
}

add_filter('img_caption_shortcode_width', 'my_img_caption_shortcode_width', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

works ;) thanks

```
.wp-caption {
/* Force the box to be 100% */
width: 100% !important;
}

#content .wp-caption a img {
/* Scale down if too big */
max-width: 99.03225806%; /* 614/620 */
height: auto;
}
```